# AJAX isn't getting applied to form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code but my AJAX isn't working. I've included the jQuery library file but the program just won't load up the PHP file when I call on AJAX. As you'll see below, the .ajax call has a URL to "mail.php" but on submit, this file never loads. I can manually name the action tag for the form to "mail.php" but that just loads up "mail.php", which defeats the point of AJAX. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" name="myForm" action="tac.php">
    <label>Name:</label> <br /> 
    <input name="sender">
    <br /> <br /> 

    <label>Email address:</label><br />
    <input name="senderEmail">
    <br />
    <label>Message:</label> <br /> 
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="message"></textarea>
    <br /> <br /> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 

      $("#myForm").submit(function() {

    var roy = new Object();
    roy.sender = $('#sender').val();
    roy.senderEmail = $('#senderEmail').val();
    roy.message = $('#message').val();

    var jo = JSON.stringify(roy);

   $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: {roy: jo},
            success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
            }

      });
    return false;
    });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: `action="tac.php"` and `url: "mail.php"` - conflict?

Comment: open the console using F12 key and see what error you are getting, if any..

Comment: @Fred-ii- The .ajax is supposed to override the form's action url, and even if I change the "tac.php" to "mail.php", it still doesn't process the form behind the scenes like AJAX is supposed to.

Comment: @VikasArora No errors, the ajax call doesn't go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="tac.php">
```

To

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="tac.php">
```

This code

```
$("#myForm")
```

is looking for an element with id="myForm" not name="myForm"

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are trying to trigger an event of an id that doesn't exist.

`$("#myForm").submit(function() {` the id "myForms" it doesn't exist on < form > tag

put id="myForm" in < form > and it will work fine.

Like this: `<form method="post" id="myForm" action="tac.php">` and also remove the name="myForm" because it has no use on form tags ...